# Data fetching in a one to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to fetch data from my database but I am stuck when I try to get data from another table.

This is what I want to do, when a user login to the web page, he would be able to see a list of people name. By clicking on their name, user will be redirected to another page which will show the person details such as name, address and email. But because there is so many of them (assuming around 200 people)

Questions:

Q1. how do I redirect the user to another page which is the name (eg: jack, user click on jack name, jack id = 1, how do I relate it back to the user_id = 1 which is the foreign key)

Q2. how do I do a loop to get their information instead of specifying it 1 by 1 (eg: I don't want to keep saying id=1, is there something like id++ which will help auto add)

This is how it looks like with my code: (picture I took from the internet but it something similar to this)
[image]

home.blade.php

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><strong><big>Name AS PER NRIC/PASSPORT: </big></strong></th>
      </tr>
      <td>
      <tr>
        @foreach($data as $value)
      <tr>    
      <th><a href="www.google.com"> {{$value->Name}}</a></th> --> I don't know how to redirect it to show user details              
      </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
    public function getData(){
        $data['data'] = DB::table('personal_infos')->get()->sortByDesc('upload_time');
        if(count($data)>0){
        return view('home',$data);
}else{
    return view('home');
}
}
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/test','testController@getData');
```

personal_info model

```
class personal_info extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('Email', 'Name', 'address');
    protected $table = 'personal_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public function user_infos() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\user_info,'user_id');
    }
        public function user_info1s() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\user_info1','user_id');
    }
}
```

user_info and user_info1 model

```
class user_info1 extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('hobby','sport','user_id');
    public function personal_infos() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\personal_info', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

Comment: `personal_infos::with('user_info1s')->get()`?

Comment: @madlinivascu I have tried that already but it only work abit, I wanted to get the data based on their user id from different table

Answer (score 0):

First add a route like

```
Route::get('/test/{id}','testController@getPerson')->name("showPerson");
```

Then setup a redirect

```
<a href="{{route('showPerson', $value)}}">
```

Use this line instead of your href="www.google.com"

Make getPerson() from testController return a new page, on that page, print out all the info of a person.

I would also suggest you google Laracast and watch all of the free videos. They're about 30 and they give you a good understanding of the laravel framework

Comment: but how do you relate it back together? For example Jack name from personal_infos table link with user_infos and user_info1s table. I only know how to do it through the view folder but not in the controller

Comment: I know I need to do something like SELECT * FROM user_infos, user_info1s,personal_infos WHERE user_id = personal_infos id(sry I can't remember how to write this part) but you should know what I mean

Comment: Let's say that $value is Jack. Laravel has already selected all of the objects will all of their data. So getting user_infos is as simple as saying $value->user_infos on the right value. Try to dump the array of people in your testController. This will give you an overview of all the people and all of the info that their objects posses.

Again, I strongly recommend you spend time watching Laracast series on Laravel before you go any further. They have free and high-quality tutorials that will help you understand Laravel better.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the link of your page to redirect you to the detail page:

```
<th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->id])}}"> {{$value->Name}}</a></th>
```

route should be:

```
Route::get('user/show/{id}','testController@getInfo')->name("user.show");
```

controller should be:

```
public function getInfo($id) {
  $user_info1 = user_info1::where('user_id',$id)->get();
  return $user_info1;//change this with your view
}
```

Comment: But what if there is another table? For example user_infos table and user_info1s table data, I want to get both of them based on the id from personal_infos table

Comment: then you add another call to the db `$user_infos table = user_infos table::where('user_id',$id)->get();`

Comment: and you return both of them

Comment: I'm having this error "Property [hobby] does not exist on this collection instance. " In my view, all I did was just put this "{{ $user_info1->hobby }};" While I used your command as like this "public function getInfo($id) {
  $user_info1 = user_info1::where('user_id',$id)->get();
  return view('test', compact('user_info1'));" I add the compact because there was an undefined variable user_info1 error in the view page

Comment: can you paste the result of `return $user_info1` you don't have a row named hobby in your user_info1 table

Comment: The result is just this "Property [hobby] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\EvalForm\resources\views\test.blade.php)"   The error is pointing to this part "<?php echo e($user_info1->hobby); ?>;"

Comment: which is inside my view page, I was just trying to get 1 of the data only, I try to search on google but they said that I need to use foreach loop to get the properties